# Using PM2 to run a complete development environment

Tags: node.js, bash, mongodb, pm2

I'm using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to run my Node microservices, and in development I would also like to start MongoDB so that I can be up and running for development with a single command. I have a development ecosystem.js file that looks something like this:

```
apps: [
        {
            name: 'API',
            script: 'index.js',
            out_file: './logs/api.stdout.log',
            error_file: './logs/api.stderr.log'
        },
        {
            name: 'Emailer',
            script: 'services/emailer/index.js',
            out_file: './logs/emailer.stdout.log',
            error_file: './logs/emailer.stderr.log'
        },
        {
            name: 'MongoDB',
            script: 'services/development/mongodb.sh'
        }
    ]
```

and `mongodb.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mongod
```

When I start PM2, everything runs just fine. When I call `pm2 stop all`, it kills the node processes, but doesn't kill MongoDB.

I'm guessing that this is because it's attaching to the bash instance, not the mongod instance. Is there a way to make PM2 start and attach to an executable, rather than a script file?

Answer (score 1):

As you know;

> PM2 is a production process manager for Node.js / io.js applications
>   with a built-in load balancer. It allows you to keep applications
>   alive forever, to reload them without downtime and to facilitate
>   common system admin tasks.

So it has no promise for attaching executables or daemonized utilities. But attaching bash script file is a very handy thing on PM2. In my opinion if when stopped it closes bash process, mongo daemon will still live in this case you faced. So you may catch bash script exit situation and while stopping pm2 processes that caught exit situation you will be able to call `mongod --shutdown` command.

Or another solution create a `start` and `stop` scripts and run and stop daemonized utilities in these bash scripts like mongodb.

Extra solution is *Docker?*

Comment: That's an excellent idea. My brain was stuck on `pm2 stop all` being the only thing that I called and it took care of everything, but for some reason I totally didn't realize that I could make a script that runs on `npm stop` that manually quits Mongo *and* calls `pm2 stop all`